# Photoshop and browser: how to get the colors right?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, color-profile

Ok, I'm designing for the web and I had different colors in Photoshop (Windows) and Chrome, so I started searching and found contradicting tips and I have no idea of what should I do now.

### Windows

- What should I set my monitor (Dell 2209WA) ICC profile to? sRGB IEC61966-2.1? Dell 2209WA? sRGB virtual device model profile?

### Photoshop

- What should I set my RGB working space to? (Edit->Color Settings) sRGB IEC61966-2.1? Monitor RGB?
- Should I use Proof Colors? in which setting? sRGB or Monitor RGB?
- Should I check "Embed Color Profile"? and what about Convert to sRGB? which setting in "Preview"? Monitor color or Internet Standard RGB?

Right now I have sRGB in my color profile, both in Windows and Photoshop, and the checkboxes disabled when saving for the web. The colors are right when I export, but I see them wrong in Photoshop, unless I set the Proof Colors to Monitor RGB every time I open a document, which is quite annoying to be honest.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/photoshop-color-settings-for-web-design?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, @Scott, so basically I should leave it like I have it right now, but check the "Convert to sRGB" just in case, it seems. 

With those settings, though, I run into the problem of miss-matched colors in Photoshop and the browser, unless I check "Proof Colors" with "Monitor RGB", is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: It would be a bit counter productive not to have proof colors enabled. After all that's mostly what you pay for with Photoshop.

Comment: @joojaa I don't have any problems with Proof Colors, but the thing is that in a rush I might forget to activate it and design with slightly different colors.

Can't I change some setting in Windows or Photoshop to avoid having this difference in color? Thanks!